# How Can I Color geoJSON features differently based on their id? Google Maps Vonroi

Tags: javascript, css, geojson

This is website atm:
https://domcindor.github.io/

And here is a mockup what I want to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycORv.png

Left side is how currently is, right side is what I want to achieve.

At this moment I have around 30 locations, 15 of them belong to one region and other 15 belong to second region.

They are both blue now, I would like to color one region in blue, and other one in red (lines and circles)

For example:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "id": 1,
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      13.751333,
      45.21376
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "XYZ"
  }
},
```

If ID == 1, color in blue
If ID == 2, color in red

I am only missing few lines above 'stroke' and 'fill'

Any help is great!

```
d3.json("data/clusters.geojson", function(pointjson) {
  main(pointjson);
});

function main(pointjson) {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.4737849, 16.4688717)
  });

  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

  overlay.onAdd = function() {
    var layer = d3
      .select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer)
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "SvgOverlay");
    var svg = layer.append("svg");
    var svgoverlay = svg.append("g").attr("class", "AdminDivisions");

    overlay.draw = function() {
      var markerOverlay = this;
      var overlayProjection = markerOverlay.getProjection();

      var googleMapProjection = function(coordinates) {
        var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(
          coordinates[1],
          coordinates[0]
        );
        var pixelCoordinates = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(
          googleCoordinates
        );
        return [pixelCoordinates.x + 4000, pixelCoordinates.y + 4000];
      };

      var pointdata = pointjson.features;

      var positions = [];

      pointdata.forEach(function(d) {
        positions.push(googleMapProjection(d.geometry.coordinates));
      });

      var polygons = d3.geom.voronoi(positions);

      var pathAttr = {
        d: function(d, i) {
          return "M" + polygons[i].join("L") + "Z";
        },
        stroke: "blue",
        fill: "none"
      };

      svgoverlay
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(pointdata)
        .attr(pathAttr)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "cell")
        .attr(pathAttr);

      var circleAttr = {
        cx: function(d, i) {
          return positions[i][0];
        },
        cy: function(d, i) {
          return positions[i][1];
        },
        r: 5,
        fill: "blue"
      };

      svgoverlay
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(pointdata)
        .attr(circleAttr)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr(circleAttr);
    };
  };
  overlay.setMap(map);
}
```